# In a G.P. the sum of the first five terms is $80$, if the difference between the sixth and first term is $5$, find the first term and common ratio.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Question :** In a G.P. the sum of the first five terms is $80$, if the difference between the sixth and first term is $5$, find the first term and common ratio.

Ths question looks easy but I am not getting the answer, maybe I am making a mistake. Can I see how you will solve it so I can check where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Can we do the other way round, you type out your solution, we match it with ours, and tell where you are going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  In particular, for an exercise such as this, you should include what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive answers that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.   Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typet mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a(1+r+r^2+r^3+r^4)=80$, and $ar^5-a=5$. We can factorise $r^5-1=(r-1)(1+r+r^2+r^3+r^4)$ then eliminate $r$ from the equations.

Using the above factorisation in the second equation we get $a(r-1)(1+r+r^2+r^3+r^4)=5$. Dividing this by the first equation gives $r=1.0625$.

To find $a$ substitute our value of $r$ back in, giving $a=\frac{5}{1.0625^5-1}$.